# Bash - Search for a specific string in a file and replace with immediate source

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I am trying to search for the string "missing" in a file containing the following:

```
<message>
    <source>TypeA</source>
    <translation>missing</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>TypeB</source>
    <translation>missing</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>TypeC</source>
    <comment>Context menu</comment>
    <translation>missing</translation>
</message>
```

And if the "missing" is found, I want to replace the string with it's immediate source name. For example this:

```
<message>
    <source>TypeA</source>
    <translation>TypeA</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>TypeB</source>
    <translation>TypeB</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>TypeC</source>
    <comment>Context menu</comment>
    <translation>TypeC</translation>
</message>
```

I was able to use awk to search for the string and print immediate source name so far:

```
match($0, /<source>(.*)<\/source>/,n){ src=n[1] }
match($0, /<translation>(.*)<\/translation>/,s){ trs=s[1] }
/unfinished/{ print "Translation missing or incomplete for: '" trs "'","located inside source named: '" src "'" }
```

And then save it as `something.awk` call it using:

```
awk -f something.awk filelocation
```

But I am not sure how to replace the string "missing" with the value from source.

Can anyone suggest me how can I replace it?

Comment: Problem is : Your XML may not respect the order of source and translation tags. Are you sure source tag always precede the translation tag ? If not, parsing with awk may not be a good solution..

Comment: @CorentinLimier. The translation tag is not always immediately after the source tag. Sometimes there is a comment tag in between. I have updated the question.

Comment: @CorentinLimier, if it's not a good idea to parsing it with AWK, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Russo is your input file well-formed xml document?

Comment: @Kent, Yes. It's a well formed XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (write this in something.awk):

```
{
    if($0 ~ "<source>"){
            source = gensub(/.*<source>(.*)<\/source>.*/, "\\1", "", $0)
    }
    if($0 ~ "<translation>missing"){
            $0 = gensub(/>.*</, ">" source "<", "", $0)
    }
     print
}
```

I don't know if you need a specific version of awk to use gensub... (maybe gawk ?). But it works on my computer when I do :

```
awk -f something.awk filelocation
```

Result :

```
<message>
    <source>TypeA</source>
    <translation>TypeA</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>TypeB</source>
    <translation>TypeB</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>TypeC</source>
    <comment>Context menu</comment>
    <translation>TypeC</translation>
</message>
```

As I said, it can be a serious problem if order of tags is not respected (or if you have multiple tags per line, ...). It is not a big deal if you have a tag between source and translation but source must be before translation. If it is not the case, you may need to parse your file with a correct XML parser tool (awk iksn't) and do your changes and print to file.

Comment: maybe `source` should be unset for each message

Comment: In my XML, the source will always come before translation and there is no chance to have multiple tags per line. Thank you.

Comment: You do need gawk for this (and maybe some versions of mawk) for gensub(). FYI `$0~/foo/` = `/foo/`.

Answer (score 5):

Even though you have accepted the answer, I would add this one.

In your comment, you told us that your input file is a well-formed xml document. So I would handle it in xml way. I love awk/sed/grep, however I have to say they (and regex) are really not the right tools to process xml files, though it works quick and dirty sometimes.

There is command line tool: `xsltproc`, which could transform xml document into other format by xslt.

The xslt is also relative simple: (save it as `f.xslt`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="translation[.='missing']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="../source"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

what you need to do is just :

```
xsltproc f.xslt input.xml
```

Test a bit with your input file: (**I added one root element**)

```
kent$  cat f.xml
<root>
        <message>
                <source>TypeA</source>
                <translation>missing</translation>
        </message>
        <message>
                <source>TypeB</source>
                <translation>missing</translation>
        </message>
        <message>
                <source>TypeC</source>
                <comment>Context menu</comment>
                <translation>missing</translation>
        </message>
</root>

kent$  xsltproc f.xslt f.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
        <message>
                <source>TypeA</source>
                <translation>TypeA</translation>
        </message>
        <message>
                <source>TypeB</source>
                <translation>TypeB</translation>
        </message>
        <message>
                <source>TypeC</source>
                <comment>Context menu</comment>
                <translation>TypeC</translation>
        </message>
</root>
```

This is gonna always work, as long as your input xml is well-formed. It's ok even if your input xml in a single line, or other format.

Comment: Hey this is cool, `xsltproc` so this tool itself will able to find missing entries and add them into the xml? that's really cool.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thx. `match="translation[.='missing']"` will locate the `translation` tag with value `missing`. And `<xsl:value-of select="../source"/>` will set the correct `source` value to it. All are xslt tricks.

Comment: Great, this is AWESOME. Could you please do guide me for some nice documentation, I am trying to google it(for `xsltproc`) but thought to check with expert here too :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 if you were new to xslt, this may show you the way: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use your output as a Variable and pass it to sed to replace, in my idea simplicity makes it perfect,

```
sed s/'$AWK_RESULT/"REPALACE_STATE"/g'
```

you will be able to use it inside a loop during you iterate your hole text as well.

Comment: That will fail if AWK_RESULT contains regexp metachars or forward slashes or can appear in other contexts or can appear in the expected context as part of another string or.... It only **looks** simple because it doesn't actually work robustly. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why the loop you suggested is a bad idea.